# Java class that automatically listens on a port for specific string(s)?

Tags: java

I have a very basic need.  I want to listen on a specific port for any one of a hand full of basic administration commands like "STOP" or "reboot".  For now I don't even care about verifying who the messages come from.

Now I can obviously create a serversocket, have it spawn a listener for each new socket, then buffer messages to look for one I'm expecting, I've done that all before it's not impossible to do.

However, I'm wondering if there is some Java class or library out there that does most of that work for me.  Something less robust as a full JAX-RS server but still per-written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using one of these, would be easier than writing from scratch:

http://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/1356891/A-PatternFramework-for-ClientServer-Programming-in-Java.htm

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/Agenericframeworkforaflexiblemultithreadedserver.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
private void startTcpServer() {
ServerSocket serversocket = null;
try {
    serversocket = new ServerSocket(TCP_SERVER_PORT);
    //accept connections
    Socket socket = serversocket.accept();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    //receive a message
    String incomingMsg;
    while((incomingMsg = in.readLine())!=null){
        Log.i("TcpServer", "received: " + incomingMsg);
        // compare incomingMsg with your list of commands
    }
    socket.close();
} catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
    //if timeout occurs
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (serversocket != null) {
        try {
            serversocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}